# Tensorflow saved model does not contain input names

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.x

We are currently training an object detection model in tensorflow 2.4.0 which is working fine. However, to be able to serve it we need to wrap it with an image pre-processing layer that takes the image bytes as input and converts them to the image tensor required by the detection model. See the following code:

```
png_file = 'myfile.png'
input_tensor = tf.io.read_file(png_file, name='image_bytes')

def preprocessing_layer(inputs):

    image_tensor = tf.image.decode_image(inputs, channels=3)
    image_tensor = tf.expand_dims(
        image_tensor, axis=0, name=None
    )
    return image_tensor 

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(tensor=input_tensor, dtype=tf.dtypes.string, name='image_bytes', batch_size=1),
        tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda inp: preprocessing_layer(inp)),
        yolo_model
    ]
)
model.summary()
```

This wrapped model provides useful detection and if we call `model.input_names` the correct names are returned: `['image_bytes']`.

Now if we save the model using `model.save('model_path')` the saved model does not contain the input names anymore and replaces them with generic ones (`args_0`).

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['args_0'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: ()
        name: serving_default_args_0:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['model'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 64512, 6)
```

This is a problem because tensorflow serving relies on the name ending with `_bytes` to convert base64 input.

Would you please provide hints on how to retain the input names when saving the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the way you defined your lambda layer, and the way you setup your model.

Your lambda function should be able to treat a batch, which is currently not the case. You can naively use `tf.map_fn` to make it handle a batch of images, like so:

```
def preprocessing_layer(str_inputs):
    def decode(inputs):
        image_tensor = tf.image.decode_image(inputs[0], channels=3)
        image_tensor = tf.expand_dims(
            image_tensor, axis=0, name=None
        )
        return image_tensor
    return tf.map_fn(decode, str_inputs, fn_output_signature=tf.uint8)
```

Then you can define your model using a symbolic `tf.keras.Input`, setting the shape to `()` (to specify no dimension other that the batch size) :

```
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input((), dtype=tf.dtypes.string, name='image_bytes'),
        tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda inp: preprocessing_layer(inp)),
        yolo_model
    ]
)
```

Now the model is correctly created, and the signature can be correctly exported.

Comment: thanks for this hint! It helped us a lot figuring out the solution